# C++ - Recursive program, Divide and conquer

Tags: c++, recursion

I have to develop the following recursive program in c ++.

The program uses a vector that is even, and has the following form.

```
[a,n,d,f]
```

The algorithm has to use divide and conquer.

The idea of ​​the algorithm is as follows, you have to compare and determine how many pairs there are.

For example, using the last vector, I have to count the number of valid couples on it, excluding the couples that **contains the "n" letter.**

For vector [a,n,d,f] we have only two couples, the first one is [a,n] and the second couple is [d,f] , couple [n,d] isn't used, so the result for this vector should be one.

Another example with the following vector, [a,b,n,d,e,f], the couples are [a,b] -> **valid** [n,d] -> **not valid** and [e,f] -> **valid**, so the result is 2, couples [b,n][n,d][d,e] are not couples for the problem.

The only valid couples for the problems depending on it size should be **v[0] with v[1]** and **v[2] with v[3]** ... v[n-1]v[n]

Here is my method, using divide and conquer, that will count the couples of valid numbers, but I dont really know how to focus it.

```
struct Solucion {
  int suma = 0;
  bool ok = false;
};

Solucion sum (vector<string>const &v, int ini, int fin) {
    Solucion sol,der,izq;

    if(ini==fin) {//Ningún elemento
        sol.suma = sol.suma;
    }else if (ini+2 == fin) { //2 elementos
        if (v[ini] != "n" && v[ini+1] != "n") {
            sol.suma = sol.suma + 1;
        }
    }
    else{ //vector 2 elementos
        int m = (ini + fin + 1) / 2;


        /*cout << "fin " << fin << endl;
        cout << "ini " << ini << endl;*/

        if (v[m] != "n" && v[m+1]!= "n" && (fin-m)==2) { //caso 2 elemtos
            sol.suma = sol.suma + 1;
        }else if (v[m] != "n" && v[m+1]!= "n" && (fin-m)==1){
            sol.suma = sol.suma + 1;
        }else {
            izq = sum(v,ini,m);
            der = sum(v,m,v.size());
        }
        sol.suma = der.suma + izq.suma;
    }


    return sol;
}
```

I do not know when to call recursion, for the left (**izq**) or right (**der**) case.

**here is my code online :** https://repl.it/repls/FlashyFrivolousWeaverbird

Comment: What makes a couple valid? Also why does this need to done with recursion? From the looks of it, a simple for loop would be far easier.

Comment: The pairs have to be evaluated two by two, that is v [0] with v [1], then v [2] with v [3] thus until v [n-1] up to v [n], a couple is counted for the sum if the "char" that both contain are different from the letter "n".
It is a requirement to divide and conquer.

Comment: @fiticida -- You really should be working this out with pencil and paper first before writing a program.  Trying to magically have a program work by musing over lines of C++ code isn't the way to go about doing things like this.

Comment: @fiticida ahh so is it safe to say that any couple not containing an `n` is a valid couple?

Comment: @Killzone Kid error coping it

Comment: @scohe001 yeah , correct

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie it is what I have done, the problem is that it currently tells me the values, but due to the recursion "I lose" the value of the sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention "losing the value of the sum" in the comments. A way to keep a running total with recursion is to return the result of the next function call plus whatever the current function call is contributing.

For example, if we wanted to count the even numbers in a vector:

```
int sum (vector<int>const &v, int ini, int fin) {
    if(ini >= fin) return 0; //if there's nothing to count, there's no evens
    if(v.at(ini) % 2 == 0) { //even num
        return sum(v, ini+1, fin) + 1; //we found one so add the rest + 1
    } else { //odd num
        return sum(v, ini+1, fin); //just return the sum of the rest, we have nothing to contribute
    }
}
```